# ElasticSearch / Nest MatchPhrasePrefix Stopped Working After Version Upgrade

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I upgraded from:

- ElasticSearch 2.0 to 6.6.1
- ElasticSearch.Net Nuget package 2.4.6 to 6.5.1
- NEST NuGet package 2.4.6 to 6.5.1

...and my Nest query to do a MatchPhrasePrefix stopped returning results.

The software is a search engine for web pages, and one of the features is supposed to let you limit the results to URLs that start with a certain path, like `http://example.com/blog` to see only blog posts in the search results.

I have a `mainQuery` that works fine. If the user supplies a `urlStartstWith` value the `mainQuery` gets anded together with a `bool` / `MatchPhrasePrefix` query.

The indexes contain anywhere from 100s to 1000s of documents.

Things I have tried that did not work:

- Completely rebuilt the new index
- Removed the `.Operator(Operator.And)` since it does not exist in this version of NEST (caused compile error)
- Upping "MaxExpansions" to various values all the up to 5000
- URL-Encoding `urlStartstWith`
- Removing the `.MinimumShouldMatch(1)` line

If I run this query built with the new NEST library against the old ElasticSearch version 2.0 server, it works.  So it's something that has changed under the hood in ElasticSearch itself I think.

**The Query**

```
var urlStartWithFilter = esQuery.Bool(b =>
    b.Filter(m =>
        m.MatchPhrasePrefix(pre =>
            pre
                //.MaxExpansions(5000) //did nothing
                //.Operator(Operator.And) //does not exist in new version of NEST
                .Query(urlStartsWith)
                .Field(f => f.Url))
        )
        .MinimumShouldMatch(1)
    );

mainQuery = mainQuery && urlStartWithFilter;
```

**As Requested - Start to Finish Example**

This is an example that shows the issue and is very close to how I query my actual project's index of web pages.

Get an ElasticSearch 6.6.1 instance running.  You can do this in docker via:

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.1
docker network create esnetwork --driver=bridge
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" --name elasticsearch -d --network esnetwork docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.1
```

Create a new .Net Framework 4.6.1 Console app.
Paste the following into `Program.cs`

```
using Nest;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Loader
{
    class Program
    {

        const string ELASTIC_SERVER = "http://localhost:9200";
        const string DEFAULT_INDEX = "stack_overflow_api";

        private static Uri es_node = new Uri(ELASTIC_SERVER);
        private static ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings(es_node).DefaultIndex(DEFAULT_INDEX);
        private static ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        private static bool include_starts_with = true;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteMainMenu();
        }


        static void WriteMainMenu()
        {
            //Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("What to do?");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Load Sample Data into ES");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - Run a query WITHOUT StartsWith");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Run a query WITH StartsWith");
            Console.WriteLine("[Enter] to exit.");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            var option = Console.ReadLine();

            if (option == "1")
            {
                LoadSampleData();
            }
            else if (option == "2")
            {
                include_starts_with = false;
                RunStartsWithQuery();
            }
            else if (option == "3")
            {
                include_starts_with = true;
                RunStartsWithQuery();
            }

            //- exit
        }

        private static void LoadSampleData()
        {
            var existsResponse = client.IndexExists(DEFAULT_INDEX);
            if (existsResponse.Exists) //delete existing mapping (and data)
            {
                client.DeleteIndex(DEFAULT_INDEX);
            }

            var rebuildResponse = client.CreateIndex(DEFAULT_INDEX, c => c.Settings(s => s.NumberOfReplicas(1).NumberOfShards(5)));
            var response2 = client.Map<Item>(m => m.AutoMap());

            var data = GetSearchResultData();

            Console.WriteLine($"Indexing {data.Count} items...");
            var response = client.IndexMany<Item>(data);
            client.Refresh(DEFAULT_INDEX);

            WriteMainMenu();
        }

        private static List<Item> GetSearchResultData()
        {
            var jsonPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "StackOverflowSampleJson.json");
            var jsondata = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonPath);
            var searchResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(jsondata);
            return searchResult;
        }

        private static void RunStartsWithQuery()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a search query and press enter, or just press enter to search for the default of 'Perl'.");
            var search = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
            {
                search = "Perl";
            }   

            Console.WriteLine($"Searching for {search}...");

            var result = client.Search<Item>(s => s
                .Query(esQuery => {


                    var titleQuery = esQuery.Match(m => m
                            .Field(p => p.title)
                            .Boost(1)
                            .Query(search)
                        );

                    var closedReasonQuery = esQuery.Match(m => m
                        .Field(p => p.closed_reason)
                        .Boost(1)
                        .Query(search)
                    );

                    // search across a couple fields
                    var mainQuery = titleQuery || closedReasonQuery;

                    if (include_starts_with)
                    {
                        var urlStartsWith = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/";

                        var urlStartWithFilter = esQuery.Bool(b =>
                            b.Filter(m =>
                                m.MatchPhrasePrefix(pre =>
                                    pre
                                        //.MaxExpansions(5000) //did nothing
                                        //.Operator(Operator.And) //does not exist in new version of NEST
                                        .Query(urlStartsWith)
                                        .Field(f => f.link))
                                )
                                .MinimumShouldMatch(1)
                            );

                        mainQuery = mainQuery && urlStartWithFilter;
                    }

                    return mainQuery;
                })
            );

            if (result.IsValid == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ES Query had an error");
            }
            else if (result.Hits.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
                Console.WriteLine($"Found {result.Hits.Count} results:");

                foreach (var item in result.Hits)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"    {item.Source.title}");
                }
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                Console.WriteLine($"Found 0 results");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            }

            WriteMainMenu();

        }
    }


    public class Item
    {
        public List<string> tags { get; set; }
        //public Owner owner { get; set; }
        public bool is_answered { get; set; }
        public int view_count { get; set; }
        public int answer_count { get; set; }
        public int score { get; set; }
        public int last_activity_date { get; set; }
        public int creation_date { get; set; }
        public int last_edit_date { get; set; }
        public int question_id { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public int? accepted_answer_id { get; set; }
        public int? closed_date { get; set; }
        public string closed_reason { get; set; }
        public int? community_owned_date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

- Create a new file called StackOverflowSampleJson.json and paste in the contents of this sample JSON: https://pastebin.com/s5rcHysp
- Set `StackOverflowSampleJson.json` to output to the build directory by right-clicking it, choosing properties, and changing `Copy to Output Directory` to `Always`
- Run the app.
- Choose `1 - Load Sample Data into ES` to populate the index
- Choose `2 - Run a query WITHOUT StartsWith` to run the query without the `StartsWith` / `MatchPhrasePrefix` to see that a normal query works
- Choose `3 - Run a query WITH StartsWith` to see that the inclusion of that extra query brings the result count to zero.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a complete example of what doesn't work, to be able to work with?

Comment: @RussCam I added an extra runnable example that illustrates the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't really understand why the old query worked with elasticsearch 2.0 and not with elasticsearch 6.6, but changing the inner query to this has gotten it working with both ES2 and ES6:

```
if (include_starts_with)
{
    var urlStartsWith = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/";

    var urlStartWithFilter = esQuery.MatchPhrasePrefix(pre => pre
        .Query(urlStartsWith)
        .Field(f => f.link)
    );

    mainQuery = mainQuery && urlStartWithFilter;
}
```